# Multivalue combobox creates multiple records in form

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have a form that has multiple comboboxes.  Some of them allow multiple values and some of them don't.  One of the comboboxes that allows multiple values is causing duplicate entries in the form records.

I can't find any differences in the property sheet between the combobox that isn't working and those that are.

**Example fields in the form:**

- Patient Account Number
- Date of Admission
- Location of Patient (combobox that allows multiple values; working correctly)
- Interface Used (combobox that allows multiple values; working correctly)
- Interventions (combobox that allows multiple values; NOT working correctly)

When I select more than one Intervention it duplicates the record within the form. I have 5 patients entered into the form, but one of them has 3 Interventions selected.  So instead of showing "1 of 5" records at the bottom of my form I see "1 of 8" and 3 of them are exactly the same.  When I look at my parent table though, there are still only 5 records.

Please forgive me if I didn't call something the proper name.  I'm very new to Access. Thank you! I tried to add screenshots, but I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: This does not seem like enough information to recreate or diagnose the problem. Perhaps you can share more details about your form or can show the property sheets.

Comment: @MrFlick, I have tried to add some additional information.  I can't add a screenshot or I would.

Comment: I suspect that the form's underlying query (=`RecordSource`) is using the `Value` property of the multivalue field. If so, remove `Value` from the query.

Comment: @EMett, I can't find a label for "RecordSource". When I look at the Data tab in the Property Sheet my "Row Source" is a query to select the ID and Text (the only two columns in that lookup table). The "Row Source Type" is set to Table/Query. Other properties include: "Limit to List"=Yes; "Allow Value List Edits"=No; "Inherit Value List"=No; "Show Only Row Source Values"=No....Am I looking in the wrong place to make sure that the Value property is not selected?

Comment: @user3613540 You are looking at the properties of the combobox! You need the properties of the form.

Comment: @EMett, you were right! Somehow I had the query pulling from my parent table and that one specific look up table, which was messing it up.  As soon as I removed the second table from the query it started working perfectly! Thank you SO much for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the form's underlying query (=`RecordSource`) is using the `Value` property of the multivalue field. If so, remove `Value` from the query.

Answer (score 0):

view the query's SQL and look for the word .Value
remove the word Value and the period before it then re-run the query the results will change back to normal amount of records and so will your form or report.